# JQuery Mobile: Adjusting Width and Height of Grouped Select

Tags: select, jquery-mobile, height, width

I had a problem before positioning grouped select but fortunately been fixed. now I am having problems with resizing, adjusting width/height of the grouped select. If there is anyone who can help me I will greatly appreciate it. below is my code...

this is my code to position it on the screen, even if i add width and height to this it seems like it is not updating. I also noticed that the width changes based on the length of the selected item. eg is when i select "September" the width of the grouped select is longer than the "March" one.

```
$("#ui-5").css({'position':'absolute','left':'6.0px','top':'57.0px'});
```

this is the code of the actual object

```
<div id="ui-5">
<div class="ui-select" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
    <select data-native-menu="false" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" id="Datepicker_0_0" name="Datepicker_0_0">
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <select data-native-menu="false" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" id="Datepicker_0_1" name="Datepicker_0_1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select data-native-menu="false" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" id="Datepicker_0_2" name="Datepicker_0_2">
        <option value="1">1975</option>
        <option value="2">1976</option>
        <option value="3">1977</option>
        <option value="4">1978</option>
        <option value="5">1979</option>
        <option value="6">1980</option>
        <option value="7">1981</option>
        <option value="8">1982</option>
        <option value="9">1983</option>
        <option value="10">1984</option>
        <option value="11">1985</option>
        <option value="12">1986</option>
        <option value="13">1987</option>
        <option value="14">1988</option>
        <option value="15">1989</option>
        <option value="16">1990</option>
        <option value="17">1991</option>
        <option value="18">1992</option>
        <option value="19">1993</option>
        <option value="20">1994</option>
        <option value="21">1995</option>
        <option value="22">1996</option>
        <option value="23">1997</option>
        <option value="24">1998</option>
        <option value="25">1999</option>
        <option value="26">2000</option>
        <option value="27">2001</option>
        <option value="28">2002</option>
        <option value="29">2003</option>
        <option value="30">2004</option>
        <option value="31">2005</option>
        <option value="32">2006</option>
        <option value="33">2007</option>
        <option value="34">2008</option>
        <option value="35">2009</option>
        <option value="36">2010</option>
        <option value="37">2011</option>
        <option value="38">2012</option>
        <option value="39">2013</option>
        <option value="40">2014</option>
        <option value="41">2015</option>
        <option value="42">2016</option>
        <option value="43">2017</option>
        <option value="44">2018</option>
        <option value="45">2019</option>
        <option value="46">2020</option>
        <option value="47">2021</option>
        <option value="48">2022</option>
        <option value="49">2023</option>
        <option value="50">2024</option>
        <option value="51">2025</option>
        <option value="52">2026</option>
        <option value="53">2027</option>
        <option value="54">2028</option>
        <option value="55">2029</option>
        <option value="56">2030</option>
        <option value="57">2031</option>
        <option value="58">2032</option>
        <option value="59">2033</option>
        <option value="60">2034</option>
        <option value="61">2035</option>
        <option value="62">2036</option>
        <option value="63">2037</option>
        <option value="64">2038</option>
        <option value="65">2039</option>
        <option value="66">2040</option>
        <option value="67">2041</option>
        <option value="68">2042</option>
        <option value="69">2043</option>
        <option value="70">2044</option>
        <option value="71">2045</option>
        <option value="72">2046</option>
        <option value="73">2047</option>
        <option value="74">2048</option>
        <option value="75">2049</option>
        <option value="76">2050</option>
    </select>
</div></div>
```

**UPDATE**
after some experimentation this is the solution [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfGmJ/12/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this style in your css

```
#Datepicker_0_0-button{
  width:200px;
}
```

This should be way you define it - `#<id of your select>-button{}`

Comment: #<id of your select>-button{} you mean #ui-5-button{}?

Comment: no..id of the select element.For 1st select it is Datepicker_0_0 right.

Comment: i tried $("#ui-5 .ui-select #Datepicker_0_0").css({'width':'600px'}); and $("#Datepicker_0_0").css({'width':'600px'}); but they doesnt seem to work. even though i dont add it in the css this javascript should change its appearance after loading the object right? but it doesnt work

Comment: Even if you add like that,the width of the button is being determined by the #Datepicker_0_0-button style.Thats why your code is not reflected.So what you have to do is override that style.

Comment: thanks for this. it seems like this resizing issue using javascript has been fixed in the RC1/RC2. http://jsfiddle.net/nfGmJ/11/