# JQuery Mobile select list - Fixed width in native menu mode (Android)

Tags: jquery, mobile, selectlist

I am using a select list using JQuery Mobile, Phonegap for Android platform. The items in the select list have varying number of characters. The width of the select list changes depending on the length of the selected item.

How do we keep the width of the select list fixed with native-menu="true" option set.

I found this but it is for native-menu="false":

[JQuery Mobile: Adjusting Width and Height of Grouped Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682914/jquery-mobile-adjusting-width-and-height-of-grouped-select)

Answer (score 0):

**Try to set Fixed width to select menu via CSS:**

```
select
{
width:150px ! important ;
}
```